# beamer and forest

Tags: beamer, trees, forest

I am preparing beamer presentation and flow chart using forest. For some reason, it is suggesting extra `}` or problem with `\end{frame}`.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\author{Dr Vaibhav Banait, }
\title{Hepatitis B and C (For healthcare workers)}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering


\begin{forest}
[Exposure to infected blood
[acute hepatitis b
[recovery]
[Carrier state]
[Chronic hepatitis B
[Cirrhosis][Liver Cancer]
]]
[acute hepatitis c
[recovery]
[chronic hepatitis c
[Cirrhosis][Liver Cancer]
]

]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is due to the empty line left in `forest` environment:

```
[Cirrhosis][Liver Cancer]
]

]
]
```

Removing it, everything works.

A complete example (the tree has been scaled as it does not fit the frame):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\author{Dr Vaibhav Banait, }
\title{Hepatitis B and C (For healthcare workers)}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\scalebox{0.825}{
\begin{forest}
[Exposure to infected blood
[acute hepatitis b
[recovery]
[Carrier state]
[Chronic hepatitis B
[Cirrhosis][Liver Cancer]
]]
[acute hepatitis c
[recovery]
[chronic hepatitis c
[Cirrhosis][Liver Cancer]
]
]
]
\end{forest}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Will you please mark the empty line? I could not see any!Thanks and regards,         -Vaibhav

Comment: That's what I did at the beginning of the answer: it s between the two consecutive square braces. Note how in the MWE I provided, no empty line is present in the forest environment.